# how to deal with element that unsupported in browser like IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser

I enjoy developing my HTML semantics so I have added.

```
<time datetime="2019-12-12">December 12</time>
```

but after that, I have seen that MDN documentation about time element says that time isn't supported in IE.

so I have used javascript and I can make alternate for unsupported code.

so can I do that also in HTML in a certain way or somehow.

Comment: there is a library called `HTML shiv` that fix this problem https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some new library's that enable you to use freely on HTML5 without been concern about browser supports, like this [one](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html).

That may give you the possibility to develop more quickly without worrying about the browser support all the time.

You can also use javascript to solve things:

```
var dt = new Date();
var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
document.write(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<time>` tag support IE 9+, for the old version of IE browser, you could try to add the following code in the header: `document.createElement("time");`

Detail code as below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        document.createElement("time");
    </script>
    <style>
        time {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
    <p>The Cure will be celebrating their 40th anniversary on <time datetime="2018-07-07">July 7</time> in London's Hyde Park.</p>

    <p>The concert starts at <time datetime="20:00">20:00</time> and you'll be able to enjoy the band for at least <time datetime="PT2H30M">2h 30m</time>.</p>
</body>
```

More detail information about HTML5 semantic elements, please check the following articles:

[HTML5 semantic elements browser support.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)

[Supporting New Elements in IE](https://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-ie)